# Send data by using post cURL

Tags: php, curl, post

I have text file with 900 lines. (json.txt)

i should send each line by using cURL.

I'm using Zebra_cURL class to send data. and i success but with 8:24 minutes of process with 3 times of sleep(5).

Note:

i set time limit = 0 in code

i edit php.ini:

max_execution_time = 180

max_input_time = 360

My Code:

```
require_once './Zebra_cURL.php';
$curl = new Zebra_cURL();
$curl->option(array(
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT  => 10, 
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT         => 30,
));
function mycallback($result) {
    return true;
}
$start = microtime(true);
$count=0;
$stopPoint = 0;
$file = fopen("json.txt", "r");
while(!feof($file)){
    $count++;
    $line = fgets($file);
    # do same stuff with the $line
    if($line != '') $xx = ''.trim($line).'';
    // echo $xx."<br />";
    $curl->post(array(
        ''.SERVER_URL.''  =>  ''.SERVER_DATA1.$xx.'',
    ), 'mycallback');

    if(($count%250)==0){
        sleep(5);
        $stopPoint++;
    }
}
fclose($file);
$end = microtime(true);
$time = number_format(($end - $start), 2);
echo 'This page loaded in ', $time, ' seconds with stop  ', $stopPoint ,' times';
```

how i can reduce the time of execution?

Comment: what happens if `if($line != '') $xx = ''.trim($line).'';` is not true?  Reduce execution time by reducing the sleep time

Comment: You may want to remove the fopen and fgets and use file_get_content() and get every single line by using explode() so you will have a loop that repeats itself for n times instead of undefined times (in using while).. I hope you could understand & I'm not really sure.. Test and see.. and using "Vanilla curl" would be better as the class doesn't help that much it's like you're using the normal cUrl extension..

Comment: @RamRaider thank you for hint, i solved it with Riad Loukili solution.

Comment: @RiadLoukili

Thank you for your solutions. I changed fopen, fget in reading file as you told, and removed sleep function, it is reduce the execution time from 8 minutes to 3 minutes.

Actually, i tried use vailla curl as you told me, but it doesn't send variables in url as i need.

So, i back to zebra class but i use queue method. and its reduce the execution time from 3 minuets to 1.20 minute. :)

i am appreciate your help, Thank you so much.

Comment: @SamiMansour I'm glade :), don't forget to post an answer to your question so it could reach more people. Cheers